# PFQuery in UITableviewCell subclass and calling it in cellForRowAtIndex:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have this query in my view controller's `cellForRowAtIndex:`:

```
        PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
        [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object[@"creator"]];
        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            if (object) {

                PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"profileImg"];

                cell.avatar.file = file;
                [cell.avatar loadInBackground];

            }
        }];
```

I would like to move this method into my custom cell's class, is it possible somehow? I've tried to move it (with some modifications) to my cell's .m file, but I can't create a class method from this.

```
-(void) setupAvatar:(PFUser *)object {

          PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
            [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object[@"creator"]];
            [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

                if (object) {

                    PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"profileImg"];

                    self.avatar.file = file;
                    [self.avatar loadInBackground];

                }
            }];

}
```

How could I solve this issue? Is it totally wrong to make queries in the cell's class or it's ok, but I'm doing it wrong? I would really appreciate if somebody could show me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can help it, I would try to avoid doing that work in the cell subclass since it breaks the MVC pattern. There's no good reason for a view to know about Parse, that's a model's job. If at all possible I would try to flesh out a data source class for your table view controller and ask that for your image instead. I would also be super apprehensive about making a call like that in cellForRowAtIndexPath especially because it isn't synchronous. I bet you are going to run into some really strange cell reuse bugs since that method will be running often and there's not a guaranteed way to know when it will return - your cell images might start changing on their own and exhibiting a lot of other strange behavior.